# Вопросительные знаки вместо текста

Tags: php

У меня такая ошибочка в чате, что сообщения приходят знаками вопроса, вот так: `?????`.
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сравнить кодировки =) Скорее всего, cp1251 и utf8

Comment: ааааа, точно =) спасибо =)